# Open Terminal window and pre-populate with command

Tags: macos, terminal

Is it possible to use the `open` command to open a Terminal window and pass it an argument to pre-populate the new window with a specific command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, but using `osascript` rather than `open`:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "ls -l"'
```

If you want to use a `bash` variable in the script, do something like this:

```
BASHVAR="hello"
osascript<<EOF
tell app "Terminal" to do script "echo $BASHVAR"
EOF
```